# session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Headers already sent by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

I am new in object-oriented PHP. This code works well in function php but it makes some error in OOP PHP.

When i open index.php then error message as like as show below but all other code works well ::

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers 
  already sent by (output started at 
  E:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery_new\public\layout\header.php:14) in 
  E:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery_new\Includes\session.php on line 15

  Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter -
   headers already sent (output started at 
  E:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery_new\public\layout\header.php:14) in
   E:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery_new\Includes\session.php on line 15
```

The code ::

index.php

```
 <?php  include ("../public/layout/header.php"); ?> // for design   header
<h2> Menu </h2>
 <?php

require_once ("../Includes/initiate.php");   // it makes error 
//require_once ("../Includes/user.php");    // it works 
//require_once ("../Includes/database_object.php");  // it makes error      

echo $user->full_name();
echo "<hr />";
  ?>
</div>   
  <?php  include ("../public/layout/footer.php");   ?>  // design for footer
```

user.php

```
<?php
require_once ("database.php");

 class USER extends  databaseObject {  // it makes error
//class USER {  // but it works         
     public $id; public $username; public $password;    public $firstName;
         public $lastName;
     // user authenticate   
     public static function authenticate( $username="", $password="" ) { ...  } 

     public function full_name()  {..... } // find full name
     // common database action
     public static function record_all_user() { ...  } // find all user

     public static function record_by_id($id=0) {.....} // find specific user

     public static function record_by_sql($sql="") { ...... }  // check sql
    ?>
```

header.php

```
 <html>
  <head>
 <title> Photo Gallery </title>
<link href="stylesheet/main.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
<body>
   <div id="header">
     <h1> PHOTO GALLERY </h1>
   </div>
<div id="main">
```

session.php

```
<?php
   class Session {          
    private $logged_in = FALSE;
    public $user_id;            
    function  __construct()  {
        session_start();
        $this->check_login();           
          .............................
            }

    public function is_logged_in() {....} // check loged in  

    public function login($user) { .....  }

    public function logout() {
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($this->user_id);
        $this->logged_in = FALSE;
    }

    private function check_login()  {... .}  // check login
}    

$session = new Session();
 ?>
```

initiate.php

```
 <?php
  require_once ("Config.php");
require_once ("Functions.php");
require_once ("session.php");
require_once ("Database.php");
require_once ("database_object.php");  // this makes error
require_once ("user.php");
 ?>
```

database_object.php

```
 <?php
require_once ("database.php");
   class databaseObject {

}
$newClass = new databaseObject();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't include *anything* which gets sent directly to the user before calling `session_start();` This includes whitespace, html, whatever.

Make sure that your first `<?php` does not have any whitespace before it. Make sure you are including the header *after* you call session_start. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order of your require-statements:

```
<?php
require_once ("session.php");
require_once ("Config.php");
require_once ("Functions.php");
require_once ("Database.php");
require_once ("database_object.php");  // this makes error
require_once ("user.php");
 ?>
```

The php session needs to be initiated before any content is sent to the browser.

Comment: Output would still be created before the session creation because of the order of includes in index.php. `initiate.php` is called after `header.php`, which produces output.

Comment: Your're Right. Haven't seen it, yet. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check , you may have `echo` , `print` that is giving output before your session created

Answer (score 0):

Right in your index.php file you are outputting characters to the browser:

```
 <?php  include ("../public/layout/header.php"); ?> // for design   header
<h2> Menu </h2>            <----- this line
 <?php

require_once ("../Includes/initiate.php");   // it makes error
```

You have to either move the require_once files above this line or buffer the output until you've sent all the headers.

Comment: I edit my index.php ::  <?php require_once ("../Includes/initiate.php");  ?>  // then others code and it's works

Answer (score 0):

No output should be produced prior to calling `session_start()`.

In your `index.php`, you include `../Includes/initiate.php`. In this file, you include `session.php`, which calls `session_start()` in its constructor. This produces an error because you have already produced output in index.php where you include `header.php`.